# How to make jquery hover like CSS hover?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I've made two hover effects with both jquery and css code here :

http://jsfiddle.net/UFSvN/3/

there is a difference between jquery hover and css hover. 
for jquery hover, if you move the mouse over the box for a very short moment and leave the box quickly, it will run mouse enter and mouse leave animation both and will finish them , while the mouse was not over the box after mouse-enter-animation ending...

but for css hover, if you hover the box, the hover effect will run the mouse-leave-animation if only you keep the mouse over the box until the mouse-over-animation ending/ is finished  !!!

how can I make jquery hover like css hover ?! 
I don't wanna have the whole animation completely ran when I move my mouse over the box just for a melee second !

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop currently running animations.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UFSvN/4/

In the fiddle, I passed in 'true' as an argument. This clears the animation queue. Do read the jQuery documentation; there are lots of other cool things it shows you how to do, like passing in a second argument to jump to the end of the animations.

Comment: thank, but what if I make some changes in my codes? like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/UFSvN/9/
then .stop(true) wont work for this case ..

Comment: @Pay4m What are you expecting it to do in that case... Playing the entire animation there seems like the most natural thing to me.

Comment: move the mouse 3 times over the jquery box and leave it quickly. then the animation will be ran 3 times continuously.. I don't want this to happen.. so I think the solution is to allow the animation if only the mouse is still over the box. and when it's out, stop the animation sequence..

Comment: @Pay4m Your new example is quite strange. Why are you using the .animate() method twice on the same element, at the same time, at two different speeds? I can only imagine that creates unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: is there a better way u could suggest me please ? It was a simple way to make my animation.. I didn't think on it so much.
now I'm focused on my question. I need the jquery animation to behave like css animation !

Comment: In my example fiddle, they behave the same way. The animations feel almost exactly the same too; it could just do with a very slight easing tweak.

Comment: then I have to include easing plugin.. 2 lines of more animate methods is better I guess..

Comment: Um.. No.. Animating twice at the same time is not the same as easing. Why does it have to be exactly precisely 100% the absolute same? It's going to look/feel ever so slightly different on different browsers/machines anyway.

Comment: and the last question, .stop(true) in my fiddle does not work, is that because there are more than 1 animate methods in each line ?! any alternative for the .stop() method for my case ?!

Comment: If you're talking about version 9 of your fiddle, then I see five `.animate()` methods, but no `.stop()` method. I still don't understand why you're not satisfied with my fiddle.

Comment: because I want the easing effect I've made, without including easing plugin. then I had to write more animate method for this aim.